# how to verifying hashed password php class

Tags: php, mysqli

how to verify this hashed password from php class

```
if(isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])){

    $key = '256sk0$*';
    $conditions['where'] = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'password' => password_verify($_POST['password'].$key),
        'status' => '1'

     );
```

Comment: http://php.net/password-verify - the manual shows you how to use that function.

Comment: Also if you intend to use this as conditions in a `WHERE` clause for a query, it will fail. You need to fetch the password first, then verify it against the plaintext one.

Comment: ok Thanks for that. where condition was a problem.

Answer (score -1):

encode password from post by your algorithm and compare with stored password in db.

Comment: No!.... with `password_verify()`, you retrieve the hashed password from the database, and use password_verify() to compare that hash with the plaintext password entered by the user

Comment: he is asking something that he don't understand or question has no sense.

Comment: And you clearly don't know how [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)/[password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) work